# Abstract method generations in VSCode for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a plugin for Visual Studio Code that generates stub implementations for missing abstract methods and properties for a concrete class in TypeScript?

Looked into the plugins, but could not find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Not that I've seen, but this would be really nice.

Answer (score 1):

No such plugin exists for Visual Studio Code at this time.

It's worth noting that [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and other JetBrains IDEs has this capability built in, and many more.

Comment: Thanks for the WebStorm advice.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this just shipped with TypeScript 2.2! https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/02/22/announcing-typescript-2-2